# Como corregir un VirtualHost

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-server

agradezco que me puedan colaborar con dos problemas:

1) Se ha comprado un dominio y creado un subdominio en GoDaddy los cuales apuntan a un servidor virtual de DigitalOcean con Ubuntu 16.04.

Para lo cual se ha creado el archivo pmos.conf que se encarga de la redirección para las carpetas correspondientes de cada uno.

Pero se están dirigiendo ambos al mismo directorio, aunque en el archivo de virtualhost se han declarado dos directorios diferentes.

2) Al momento de cargar tanto el dominio como el subdominio, se cambian en la URL por la ip del servidor, en lugar de mantenerse el dominio o subdominio.

Con el fin de ejemplificar mejor lo que esta fallando, comparto un video donde se demuestran los fallos a partir del minuto 3.50. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdvV9PrAMdw&t=7s)

El archivo VirtualHost completo es este:

```
####### Dorada Landing __________________
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ipsdorada.com
        ServerAlias www.ipsdorada.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dorada_landing/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/dorada_landing/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


####### Dorada ProcessMaker _________________________

 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName health.ipsdorada.com
    ServerAlias www.health.ipsdorada.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dorada/workflow/public_html

    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverRide none
    </Directory>

    <Directory  /var/www/html/dorada/workflow/public_html>
       AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
       AllowOverRide none
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]

       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
       </IfModule>

    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Espero me puedan colaborar, les agradezco mucho.

Comment: Apache o Apache2? Y puedes poner el archivo dentro de tu pregunta. Si lo borras de tu drive, la gente que tenga tu mismo problema en el futuro no podra usar esta pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Si es apache2. El archivo no será eliminado.

Comment: Las reglas del sitio no lo hacen opcional. Te recomiendo ir al [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para que veas cómo funciona. Así mismo, puedes ver [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te respondan más rápido y claro. Procura seguir las indicaciones de quienes te recomiendan mejorar tu pregunta, que sólo buscamos que te ayuden más rápido. No veo el lío con editar la pregunta, quitarle la etiqueta [apache] y pegar el contenido del virtualhost